# How to clear outbound blockage using the snake/auger?

Tags: kitchen-sink, clog

> If there is any information that I can provide to help make this a
>   better question or to assist in getting a better answer please let me
>   know in the comments and I will update.

Please check out my photo below (sorry about the quality), you can see that I've removed the trap (elbow) and I have the snake in the outbound pipe. The snake makes it to the wall (about the length of the pipe) and comes back with black gunk but can go no further. It's my first time in the kitchen area with a snake so I'm unsure what to make of this...

I guess I should try turning the snake downward somehow but before I start really mashing about down there, I've stopped (since there seems to be a hard wall or something inside). This seemed like a good point to reach out and ask someone for a bit of guidance since I don't want to make things worse.

Any thoughts on what I can do at this point or how to work that snake further down the pipe?

**Background:**

I have the issue where the kitchen sink is clogged when I turned on the garbage disposal unit, the water backed up into the two sink (about a 1/4 of the sink full). I tried the Hair and Grease drain cleaner (from Home Depot ~ the heavy duty one sold in the plastic bag) overnight and the water did drain out of the sinks. When I tried to run water through in the morning, the sinks began to backfill again.

[image: sink]

**Update:**

Per request please note the photo of the outflow pipe below.

[image: pipe]

When I tried to rotate the snake clockwise I was able to get 7-8 feet further. But afterward (maybe an hour or so later) the water starts to backfill even more after I replaced the trap and did NOT run new water down (https://youtu.be/Mcxoekjoazk). Now clear water is coming up into the sink.  In fact, the water in the kitchen sink is (several hours later) now rising to about 1/3 height of the sink.

[image: sinks]

### Final Update

> I'm posting this update for the next person having this issue. I was
>   able to use the auger on the outflow pipe (going into the wall and
>   downward). Once I did so I hit a blockage that felt like a
>   brick/cement/hard packed dirt. I then went out to Home Depot and
>   picked up a medium sized bladder(1-1/2 to 3 inches). Attached that to a water hose,
>   inserted it up to the first turn of the outflow pipe and turned on the
>   water. I noticed that the water sound changes as it eliminated the
>   blockage and became fully smooth running after 10-15 mins. I gave it
>   quite a bit more time just to make sure and now the clog appears to be
>   completely gone. Hope this helps anyone with the problem and thanks to [Ed Beal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/44366/ed-beal) for all the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see to the back of the fitting would it be possible to cut the pipe and use a coupler or union to repair when done? Each 90 causes a large amount of force to be required, with a 90 at the start then probably another 90 in a few inches that will make it tough now go down to ground level and another 90 some may be sweeps or t's but the force still jumps with each one.  Next are you spinning clock wise? You want the augger to pull into the plug turning counter clockwise actually pulls the snake out while you are pushing. Plugs can be tough to work through with a small snake but if you are pulling stuff back up you are getting close , I have power snakes and have had to hit a plug 20-30 times where other times 1 times clears the plug. If totally stuck look for another entrance to try, the roof vents are usually a good place but may require a longer snake. Some homes have a main back bone with a plug at the washing machine in the garage so there may be other ways to tackle this but if nothing else in backing up I would keep trying.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've updated the question with more details. Is it common to see water coming back into the sink once I reconnect the trap? I didn't run water in through that sink and yet it's started filling up...?

Comment: As long as the snake is going down the drain not up the vent it sounds like you are doing the correct things, I am guessing the end of the snake looks like a cork screw most do but not all. When you hit the resistance keep pressure on the snake while spining some plugs feel like cement. With water backing up into the sink I would think you have a faucet dripping some place that is filling the line, usually sinks are the highest drain in single level ranch homes. The gunk you are pulling out is what you are after, grease, soap & food residue and possibly some hair from the bath is expected.